# Java HashMap returning null values even when key is present

Tags: java, hashmap

I am working on a project in which we insert key and value pairs in a `Map`.

If the key is present in the `Map`, my code returns the value for that key.

However, the `HashMap` is not returning the expected values, even though the key is present.

First I read the key and value pairs from a file, then I read another file which has almost the same keys as the first file.

Then I return values for some keys, but for many of them the value is `null`.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("a.txt"));

LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
   String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split(";");
   map.put(columns[0], columns[1]);
}

System.out.println(map);

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{ // name is the input of second file
    if (entry.getKey().equals(name)) 
    {
        num = entry.getValue();         
        fun(num);
    }
}
```

My input file is

abc;1

def;2

ghi;3

...
and name will be
abc

def

Comment: Can you show how your text file look like?

Comment: Why the for loop, when map.get(name) would do the job?

Comment: I suspect there might be some trailing or leading whitespaces.

Comment: by using map.get(name) also it is returning null values

Comment: Please include `System.out.printf("@%s@\n", name)` outside the loop and `System.out.printf("@%s@\n", entry.getKey())` inside the loop and update the question with the output? The `@`s are to show whitespaces

Comment: @user2490712 Then go ahead and use `map.get(name)`. I highly doubt there's a bug caused by using it that wouldn't appear when you iterate  over the entry set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Strings that are being compared might have white space, linefeed, newline characters.**

As we suspected earlier your input file `train.txt` has man trailing white-spaces and that is causing map lookup to fail. Besides that your Java code had many redundant block of code. I have cleaned it up. Here is your modified code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ExampleClass1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("trainnames.txt"));
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split(";");
            map.put(columns[0].trim(), columns[1].trim());
        }
        scanner.close();
        System.out.println("******** map is: " + map);
        File file = new File("onn.csv"); // output file
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("train.txt"));
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();
            if (line.charAt(0) == '>') {
                //System.out.println("==== line: [" + line + ']');      
                String num = map.get(line);
                no(num, fileWriter);
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
        fileWriter.close();
    }

    public static void no(String num, FileWriter fileWriter) throws IOException {
        fileWriter.append(num + ',' + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        System.out.println(num);                                        
    }
}
```

Comment: `\W` contains many more characters than just whitespace. And `replaceAll` will remove all of them, not just those at the ends.

Comment: You can use `name.trim()` to remove trailing and leading whitespaces.

Comment: Yes you can definitely do that to remove white-spaces only from both ends.

Comment: Show output of `System.out.println(map);` and `System.out.println('[' + name + ']');`

Comment: output of map:{1NBG=1, 1MBD=1, 1MBM=1, 1LN1=1, 1BMBM=1, 1MLLM=1, 1DMN=2, 1CYZ=2, 5CYTR=2, 1CC5
=2, 351C=2, 1GKS=2, 1MOFM1=2, 1ETPM1=2, 1ETPM2=2, 1YRNM=3, 1YRNB=3, 1OCTC1=3, 1F
JLM=3, 1RES=3, 1PDNC=3, 1ZGNM1=3, 1ZGNM2=3, 1SFE_1=3, 1BZM_1=3, 1LEM=3, 1MOY=3,
1CGPM1=3, 1OPC=3, 1ETD=3, 1PUEE=3, 2NTS=3, 1DPRM1=3, 1XGSM1=3, 1FOW=3, 2LZGM=4,
1BBNM=4, 1CGO=4, 1CPQ=4, 2NMQM=4, 1MTMP=4, 1BUCM1=4, 1FMPB=4, 1BGC=5, 1CNT1=5}

Comment: Also show the output of: `System.out.println('[' + name + ']');`

Comment: output of System.out.println('[' + name + ']'); is [1NBG]
[1MBD]
[1MBM]
[1LN1]
[1BMBM]
[1MLLM]
[1DMN]
[1CYZ]
[5CYTR]
[1CC5]
[351C]

Comment: for some keys it is printing the values and for some it is returning null

Comment: Hmm that is really weird. If you can recreate the problem on ideone.com Java editor and share the link I will definitely investigate.

Comment: trainnames willbe in format:>1BABA;1
>1ALLA;1
>1DVH;2
>1CYI;2 every one will start in a new line

Comment: train.txt will be in format:>1BABA 
MELSPADK
>1ALLA 
SIVTKSI
>1DVH  
ADGAAL
>1CYI  
ADLALGAQVFNGNC

Comment: ok thanku but even i change my hashmap to array it is also giving the same null values i am not at able to understand please help me if you rquire i will provide the input files help me i stucked with this problem for two days..

Comment: i have send all the files to your email id

Comment: thanku for the answer and i am placing the test code in my main program

Answer (score 3):

This issue can come up if the hashCode of the object changes after insertion.

If you're modifying an object that's used as a key in a hashMap, you have two options:

1. Replace the HashMap with an IdentityHashMap. This may have unintended consequences as two objects with the same hashCode will no longer be considered equivalent when putting/getting from the map, including exact clones.
2. Before updating the key in such a way the hashCode is changed, remove it from the map, update the key, then re-insert into the map.

Comment: How do you handle this though?

Comment: @Dylan I've added some alternatives